# How to remove Gnome desktop environment?

Tags: 13.04, gnome

I had installed **Ubuntu-gnome-i386** in my laptop. It is working fine but I don't need gnome environment anymore. How can I completely remove Gnome desktop environment and get back my Unity.

Comment: Do you have installed Unity before?

Comment: Ubuntu-gnome-i386 comes by default with Gnome, I don't believe that it has unity, but I could be wrong. What I would recommend is that you keep it the way it is, and install whatever Desktop Environment that you desire. For more information on what's available, see [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-shell -y`